# Push directory timestamps into an array sorted by date in bash

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, unix, timestamp

I have the following directories:

```
1/
2/
3/
4/
5/
6/
7/
...
```

I want to loop through this list of directories and save them into an array sorted by their modification date

like

```
array[
3, #oldest timestamp
4,
5,
8,
1, #newest timestamp 
]
```

After that I want to access the array values like: array[0]

How is this possible with bash? I tried several things like this:

```
ARRAY=()
for d in */; do
ARRAY+=($[$(date +%s)-$(stat --printf "%Y" "$d")])
done
```

but nothing seems to work :(

Would be nice if someone can help :)

Comment: If you want to do this in Bash, why have you tagged the question C?

Comment: missed that >.< I'm tired because of this problem but I wan't to fix this. Sorry. Can I delete it somehow?

Comment: Just edit your question and remove it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do

```
cd /path/to/your/dir
string="$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -k 1nr | sed 's/^[^ ]* //' | tr -d './' )"
IFS=$'\n' read -rd '' -a array <<< "$string"
```

and then access elem of the array like this :

```
echo "${array[1]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this;

```
ARRAY=($(find . ! -path . -type d -printf "%T@ %Tc %f\n"  | awk '{print $NF}'))
```